# Авторизация на сложном сайте с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, auth, парсер

### Описание:

Приветствую всех.

Пишу парсер. Пытаюсь авторизоваться в аккаунт [Publisher Unity Asset Store](https://publisher.assetstore.unity3d.com/) с помощью библиотеки *Jsoup*. Но ничего не выходит, т.к. я не могу нормально получить токен.

С помощью *HTTPAnalyzer* посмотрел, что отправляется в запросе.

[image: Содержимое POST-запроса]

Как видно на скриншоте выше, в запросе есть поле authenticity_token. Находится токен на странице авторизации (первая ссылка выше) в html-коде страницы в одном из тегов `<meta>`.

**Я это описываю, чтобы было понятно, что получить токен ДО загрузки страницы нельзя. Также токен меняется при каждом обновлении страницы.**

И получается, что я следующим образом могу загрузить страницу и заполнить все поля, кроме токена.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .userAgent(client)
                    .data("utf8", "?")
                    .data("authenticity_token", "???????????")
                    .data("conversations_create_session_form[email]", "email@email.com")
                    .data("conversations_create_session_form[password]", "password")
                    .data("conversations_create_session_form[remember_me]", "true")
                    .data("commit", "Log in")
                    .execute();
```

Затем спарсить токен:

```
token = response.parse()
                        .select("meta")
                        .get(5)
                        .attr("content");
```

**Но это не будет иметь смысла, потому что запрос УЖЕ отправлен. Создание нового запроса обновит страницу и сделает спарсенный токен недействительным.**

### Вопрос: *Как отправить актуальный токен?*

Прошу не стесняться делать предположения, буду рад любой помощи :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой код у меня получился, который авторизируется и позволяет запрашивать данные с других страниц сайта.

```html
package tk.seawind.unityauth;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String token = "";
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                .connect("https://publisher.assetstore.unity3d.com/")
                .execute();
        Document doc = response.parse();
        for (Element meta : doc.select("meta")) {
            if (meta.attr("name").equals("csrf-token")) {
                token = meta.attr("content");
            }
        }
        
        response = Jsoup
                .connect("https://id.unity.com" + doc.select("form").attr("action"))
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .data("utf8", "%E2%9C%93")
                .data("_method", "put")
                .data("authenticity_token", token)
                .data("conversations_create_session_form[email]", "***@***.***")
                .data("conversations_create_session_form[password]", "********")
                .data("conversations_create_session_form[remember_me]", "true")
                .data("commit", "Log in")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .execute();
       
// С этого места мы уже авторизированны и работаем с сайтом (не забывая вставлять куки). Для проверки запросил страницу редактирования аккаунта.

        response = Jsoup
                .connect("https://id.unity.com/account/edit")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .execute();
        
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }

}
```

Comment: Вначале парсим токен на: 
https://publisher.assetstore.unity3d.com/
потом его указываем в отправляемой форме логина https://id.unity.com

Comment: Ваш способ сработал, огромное спасибо! Быть может у Вас будут идеи, как спарсить информацию со страницы, если эта информация подгружается js-скриптом и только потом вставляется в html?

Comment: Нужно использовать что-то типа этого: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
который умеет выполнять javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Получить токен на начальной странице, с ним уже авторизироватся по форме.
Как-то так:

```
    String token = "";
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("https://publisher.assetstore.unity3d.com/")
            .get();
    for (Element meta : doc.select("meta")) {
        if (meta.attr("name").equals("csrf-token")) {
            token = meta.attr("content");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Morewind. Однако вопрос не в том, как получить токен. Это я уже сделал, как видите. Если вы знаете, как после получения токена его отправить в форму, пожалуйста, напишите)